Cut the ansible-playbook output
Is any way here to reduce the ansible-playbook command output (ansible_facts in that case)? I couldn't find a way to cut the command verbosity.
My config file is
[defaults]
verbosity=0
log_path = /var/log/ansible.log
nocows=true
stdout_callback=ansible.builtin.oneline
host_key_checking = false
inventory = /root/ansible/hosts.txt
interpreter_python=auto_silent

The playbook is
---
- name: Install default Apache Web Server
  hosts: all
  become: yes

  tasks:
  - name: Install Apache WebServer
    apt: name=apache2 state=latest

  - name: Start Apache and enable it on startup
    service: name=apache2 state=started enabled=yes

Ansible collects an output to the log file.
All commands' output looks perfect, but the ansible-playbook output is enormous. There're a lot of redundant or empty JSON fields (loopX or device:"/dev/loopX"). I put a sample logline here

Callback plugins oneline (or minimal)  will print the output of modules.  They were written for ansible ad-hoc, which only runs one task. Imagine you have a dozen hosts and you just want to see the uname -a output from all of them. Easy ad-hoc command, output from all hosts fits on a screen.
Except in modern Ansible rather than one line of output you might get a complex object.
Facts modules produce a large amount of output, especially for a Linux box like that where many things are collected. Yes some data structures are redundant and otherwise strange, there exists use cases for it being like that. Filtering for what can be collected is possible, like setup module's gather_subset.
I do not think fact output in a task log read by humans is useful.  Incredibly verbose, and not likely to get smaller. Fact gathering usually just works so there is little need to debug that specifically.
Pick a different stdout callback plugin, at least for facts. Find one that does not always print the module output.  default callback is in ansible-core  for example.  Callback plugins can be set in several ways, for example environment variables: ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=default ansible-playbook
Enable a cache plugin. Using the system to store fact values allows you to collect facts in one playbook, and use them in another.  As separate playbooks they could change callback plugin and have other differences.  Also, if you wanted to refer to previous fact values, could preserve them in the cache for some time.
